# DIY ESD generator (ESD-gun)

Tags: emc, esd

Does anyone have a simple ESD generator circuit for pre-compliance testing (3-20 kV)?

e.g. can it be built from the following?
http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-High-Quality-3V-to-7KV-Boost-Step-up-Module-High-voltage-Black-1PCS-/161938513435?hash=item25b4499e1b:g:4rkAAOSwZG9WjFLj

How can it be switched fast (~20 ns) with an MCU?

Comment: Use a piezo grill igniter. The air gap will vaguely control the peak voltage, but it's a good $10 tester if your stuff is supposed to be very resilient.

Comment: It makes one hell of a shock though, so it is probably overkill for ESD testing.

Comment: @Daniel  Hah, I used the peizo igniter as a ESD tester too.  I've always wondered how much current and voltage it gives.

Comment: Socks and a carpet?

Comment: a cat or a condom. https://xkcd.com/649/

Comment: @Samuel Unfortunately that doesn't work in climates that are high humidity for most of the year.. I've seen instances of people fooling themselves on ESD because their environment doesn't generate much!

Comment: I had an office chair that I would slide off to charge me enough to give about 8mm arc! A bit rough and ready, but I found bad track layout that made a micro-controller reset pin sensitive.

Comment: The eBay link is dead.  -1 for using eBay auction as context for a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most controlled test would be to use a human model like this:

[image: Human model]

<sub>(source: [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/images/E16FigA.gif))</sub>

For the high voltage supply I would use a Cockcroft Walton voltage multiplier with an isolation transformer. For 220V mains, you'll need 9 stages.

[image: Voltage multiplier]
<sub>(source: [eet.com](http://m.eet.com/media/1170936/multiplier%201x600.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This seems like a Marx generator, is it based on it ?

Comment: marx generates pulses cockcroft generates DC

Comment: any idea how to switch the HV from the middle cap?

Comment: A high voltage relay would be the best.

Comment: Hmm 50eur for HV realy is very expensive, any cheaper solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [Van de Graff generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) very inexpensively (2 metal combs, 1 metal ball, 1 rubber/vinyl belt, 1 metal pulley & 1 non-conductive pulley, with a motor).

It would be far more predictable/controllable than a grill ignitor, or most flyback, or boost converter-type devices as you can change the capacitance by varying the top ball dimensions, and can easily monitor the building voltage with a hv-multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an electric fence generator usually used for controlling livestock.  These are very cheap and work from a 12V supply or the mains.

Comment: This probably has a different timescale than a pf capacitor found in most generators

Comment: A fence charger will deliver _way_ too much energy for this application. It'll blow traces right off the board.